# How to display HTML captions without a loaded video?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video-streaming, captions, webvtt

I want to display captions using the HTML5 Text Tracks API (WebVTT) using the native browser implementations -- without loading audio/video.

How can that be achieved ?

Comment: You mean just print out the text without any timing?

Comment: Already did that actually

Comment: Seems attaching captions to a non-active element doesn't work.. if you think there is a better way feel free to elaborate.

Comment: No, I was gonna say the API doesn't allow it. Your workaround sounds good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way using the native implementation.

However, the Firefox implementation of WebVTT, vtt.js, is [publicly available](https://github.com/mozilla/vtt.js/).

All you need to do is attach a timer while a video element is playing (or just to any custom event without a video) and apply vtt.js functions to the video / captions container.

Since the Firefox VTT implementation is derived from it, this is the closest you can come to native without using the default way of attaching to a video.